# Is the inverse image of $\emptyset$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to show that the family of sets whose inverse images are measurable is a $\sigma$-algebra, and the only part I am really having difficulty with is showing that the empty set is contained in the family.

Might be a stupid question, but how do I show that $f^{-1}(\emptyset)$ is measurable?

Comment: For a real (or more generally complex) valued function $f$, can $f(\text{something}) \in \emptyset$?

Comment: $\emptyset$ itself, I suppose. Is that all there is?

Comment: The inverse image by $f$  of $B$  is denoted by $f^{-1}(B)$  and it is defined as $$ f^{-1}(B)= \{ x \:|\: f(x)\in B\}$$ So $$ f^{-1}(\emptyset)= \{ x \:|\: f(x)\in \emptyset\}= \emptyset$$ So the inverve image of $\emptyset$ is just $\emptyset$ itself and it is measurable.

Comment: However, it is worth to note that  a family of sets whose inverse images by a function $f$ are measurable may not be  a $\sigma$-algebra, if $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: @JessyCat You're on the right track. You can't have an element sent to $\emptyset$ (since $f$ only takes real (or complex) values.. it doesn't take the empty set as a value), thus the inverse image of $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$.